# Can I seamlessly migrate users from Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If one day I would have to replace Firebase with custom solution can I migrate authorized users from **Firebase Auth** to my system?

I am aware that Firebase allows to export all user data using **Firebase Admin SDK** but I'm curious about behavior of identity providers (Facebook, Google and Twitter). If my custom system would use the same providers API keys as Firebase Auth what would happen to my users?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firebase Auth provide a CLI SDK to download your accounts:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport

Firebase Auth uses SCRYPT to hash passwords. If you decide to migrate, you can also contact Firebase support to help you with the process. 
As for linked OAuth providers, you can still implement that in your own system as the OAuth flow is a well known standard and the users should be portable. In general, Firebase Auth architecture is based on open standards and protocols that are widely used in the industry. The advantage is that Firebase Auth manages all that complexity for you for free.

Comment: Once you export the users & hashed passwords, you can use https://github.com/firebase/scrypt to verify user logins.

Comment: This API worked for me when migrating from one firebase project to another. First export as JSON then import the same file _with_ parameters found in "password hash parameters"